# Games in start menu missing

Tags: windows-7

The Games which comes with Windows have disappeared from the start menu. I have searched the Recycle Bin. The games include, Solitaire, Hearts and Patience.

Answer (score 1):

From the Control Panel open "Programs and Features". On the left side click on "Turn Windows features on or off". A dialogue box will appearer with all the Windows features. Check the Games folder (it is usually on top of the list) and click OK.

[image]